# Python BeautifulSoup is just reading the first line

Tags: python, html, csv, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Below is the code I am using for reading a table and inserting it into a csv file. But it is reading only the header and first row.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import csv
import MySQLdb
import itertools
import time

wiki = "http://10.202.215.24:8081/nmediation/cdot_ces_status_xx.jsp?userName=RJCADMIN"
time.sleep(50)
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'} #Needed to prevent 403 error on Wikipedia
req = urllib2.Request(wiki,headers=header)
page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")


table = soup.find("table" , { "border" : "1" })

rows=[]
headers = [header.text for header in table.find_all('th')]
for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    rows.append([val.text.encode('utf8') for val in row.find_all('td')])
with open('/home/hirdesh/cronrun/iop_status.csv', 'wb') as f:
     writer = csv.writer(f)
     writer.writerow(headers)
     writer.writerows(row for row in rows if row)


#to insert into db

# Establish a MySQL connection
database = MySQLdb.connect (host="localhost", user = "hfhgfh", passwd = "fghgfhfgh", db = "rghfghj")
cursor = database.cursor()
csv_data = csv.reader(file('/home/hirdesh/cronrun/iop_status.csv'))
query1='''truncate table iop_status'''
cursor.execute(query1)

file = open("/home/hirdesh/cronrun/iop_stauslog.txt", "wb")
#file.write("1.Old data deleted From Master Less table\n")
rows=len(list(csv.reader(open('/home/hirdesh/cronrun/iop_status.csv'))))
i=1
j=rows
query2='''INSERT INTO iop_status (CIRCLE, SSA, Switch, CES_NAME, CES_IP, IOP_A_STATUS, IOP_B_STATUS, IOP_TESTING_DATE, IOP_STATUS,CURNT_DATE)  VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'''

#query2='''INSERT INTO iop_status (CURRENT_DATE)  VALUES (%s)'''
for row in itertools.islice(csv_data,i,j):
    CIRCLE = row[1]
    SSA= row[2]
    Switch= row[3]
        CES_NAME= row[4]
    CES_IP = row[5]
    IOP_A_STATUS = row[6]
    IOP_B_STATUS = row[7]
    IOP_TESTING_DATE= row[8]
    IOP_STATUS = row[9]
    CURNT_DATE= row[10]

    values = (CIRCLE, SSA, Switch,CES_NAME, CES_IP, IOP_A_STATUS, IOP_B_STATUS, IOP_TESTING_DATE, IOP_STATUS,CURNT_DATE)
    cursor.execute(query2,values)
cursor.close()
database.commit()
database.close()
# Print results
file.write("2.%d Rows Inserted\n" % j)
file.write("Current date & time " + time.strftime("%c"))
file.write("*****************\n")
file.close()
```

---

Below is a section of the table I want to read using beautiful soup. On Ubuntu 14.04 it was working fine, but on Ubuntu 17.04 it is reading only the first line and header.

```
<pre>      
  <table border=1 width=70 font size=2 >
    <tr><th>S.No.</th><th>Circle</th><th>SSA</th><th>Switch</th><th>CES_NAME</th><th>CES_IP</th><th>IOP_A_STATUS</th><th>IOP_B_STATUS</th><th>IOP_TESTING_DATE</th><th>IOP_STATUS</th><th>CURRENT_DATE</th></tr>
    <tr><td height=5px>
    1
    </td><td height=5px>
    RJC
    </td><td height=5px>
    CTT
    </td><td height=5px>
    <a href="cdot_ces_status_switch.jsp?userName=CTTCDOT_PARTA">CTTCDOT_PARTA</a>
    </td><td  height=5px>
    RJ-CTG-PTG-CES
    </td><td  height=5px>
    10.84.4.30
    </td><td  height=5px>
    </th></tr>
        </body>

</pre>
```

Comment: next time use button `{}` to format code and HTML.

Comment: create minimal working example. If you save in csv then remove code which use database.

Comment: you could also put HTML in variable `page` to run it without requests. This way we can run it and test it. BTW. first you could use `print()` to check if requests gives you all expected data.

Comment: Did you try to print your `table` variable?

Comment: do you use the same Python version on both systems ? New Ubuntu can use Python 3 instead of Python 2 . Don't you get any error message when you run it in console/terminal ?

Comment: table is incorrectly constructed - last element in rows has `</th>`  instead of `</td>` and it makes problem. But if I use `"lxml"` instead of `"html.parser"` then I don't have problem to get all rows

Answer (score 1):

Table is incorrectly constructed - last element in rows has `</th>` instead of `</td>` and it makes problem.

But if I use `"lxml"` instead of `"html.parser"` then it gets all rows.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
```

Working example

```
page = '''      
<table border=1 width=70 font size=2 >
    <tr><th>S.No.</th><th>Circle</th><th>SSA</th><th>Switch</th><th>CES_NAME</th><th>CES_IP</th><th>IOP_A_STATUS</th><th>IOP_B_STATUS</th><th>IOP_TESTING_DATE</th><th>IOP_STATUS</th><th>CURRENT_DATE</th></tr>
    <tr><td height=5px>
    1
    </td><td height=5px>
    RJC
    </td><td height=5px>
    CTT
    </td><td height=5px>
    <a href="cdot_ces_status_switch.jsp?userName=CTTCDOT_PARTA">CTTCDOT_PARTA</a>
    </td><td  height=5px>
    RJ-CTG-PTG-CES
    </td><td  height=5px>
    10.84.4.30
    </td><td  height=5px>
    INS_ACT
    </td><td  height=5px>
    OOS
    </td><td  height=5px>
    28/Dec/2017 08:03:30
    </td><td  height=5px>
    <center><IMG SRC=images/Aredo.gif width=20 height=20>Disabled</center>
    </td><td  height=5px>
    02/Jan/2018 10:44:29
    </th></tr>

    <tr><td height=5px>
    2
    </td><td height=5px>
    RJC
    </td><td height=5px>
    JJN
    </td><td height=5px>
    <a href="cdot_ces_status_switch.jsp?userName=JJNCDOT_CHIRA">JJNCDOT_CHIRA</a>
    </td><td  height=5px>
    RJ-JJN-CHW-CES
    </td><td  height=5px>
    10.84.7.250
    </td><td  height=5px>
    INS_SBY
    </td><td  height=5px>
    INS_ACT
    </td><td  height=5px>
    2/Jan/2018 08:05:40
    </td><td  height=5px>
    <center><IMG SRC=images/Aredo.gif width=20 height=20>Disabled</center>
    </td><td  height=5px>
    02/Jan/2018 10:44:30
    </th></tr>

    <tr><td height=5px>
    3
    </td><td height=5px>
    RJC
    </td><td height=5px>
    JJN
    </td><td height=5px>
    <a href="cdot_ces_status_switch.jsp?userName=JJNCDOT_NAWAL">JJNCDOT_NAWAL</a>
    </td><td  height=5px>
    RJ-JJN-NWG-CES
    </td><td  height=5px>
    10.84.7.246
    </td><td  height=5px>
    INS_ACT
    </td><td  height=5px>
    OOS
    </td><td  height=5px>
    1/Jan/2018 15:08:42
    </td><td  height=5px>
    <center><IMG SRC=images/Aredo.gif width=20 height=20>Disabled</center>
    </td><td  height=5px>
    02/Jan/2018 10:44:32
    </th></tr>

    <tr><td height=5px>
    4
    </td><td height=5px>
    RJC
    </td><td height=5px>
    SRO
    </td><td height=5px>
    <a href="cdot_ces_status_switch.jsp?userName=SROCDOT_BHINM">SROCDOT_BHINM</a>
    </td><td  height=5px>
    RJ-SIR-BML-CES
    </td><td  height=5px>
    10.84.6.206
    </td><td  height=5px>
    NA
    </td><td  height=5px>
    NA
    </td><td  height=5px>
    NA
    </td><td  height=5px>
    <center><IMG SRC=images/Aredo.gif width=20 height=20>Network Down</center>
    </td><td  height=5px>
    02/Jan/2018 11:01:33
    </th></tr>

    <tr><td height=5px>
    78
    </td><td height=5px>
    RJC
    </td><td height=5px>
    BAM
    </td><td height=5px>
    <a href="cdot_ces_status_switch.jsp?userName=BAMCDOT_BARME">BAMCDOT_BARME</a>
    </td><td  height=5px>
    RJ-BMR-MAIN-CES
    </td><td  height=5px>
    10.84.4.166
    </td><td  height=5px>
    INS_ACT
    </td><td  height=5px>
    INS_SBY
    </td><td  height=5px>
    2/Jan/2018 10:12:02
    </td><td  height=5px>
    <center><IMG SRC=images/greenb.gif width=20 height=20>Enabled</center>
    </td><td  height=5px>
    02/Jan/2018 10:47:37
    </th></tr>
</body>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml") # "html.parser"

table = soup.find("table" , { "border" : "1" })

for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]: # [1:] skip header
    data = [val.text.strip().encode('utf8') for val in row.find_all('td')]
    print(data)
```

Result

```
[b'1', b'RJC', b'CTT', b'CTTCDOT_PARTA', b'RJ-CTG-PTG-CES', b'10.84.4.30', b'INS_ACT', b'OOS', b'28/Dec/2017 08:03:30', b'Disabled', b'02/Jan/2018 10:44:29']
[b'2', b'RJC', b'JJN', b'JJNCDOT_CHIRA', b'RJ-JJN-CHW-CES', b'10.84.7.250', b'INS_SBY', b'INS_ACT', b'2/Jan/2018 08:05:40', b'Disabled', b'02/Jan/2018 10:44:30']
[b'3', b'RJC', b'JJN', b'JJNCDOT_NAWAL', b'RJ-JJN-NWG-CES', b'10.84.7.246', b'INS_ACT', b'OOS', b'1/Jan/2018 15:08:42', b'Disabled', b'02/Jan/2018 10:44:32']
[b'4', b'RJC', b'SRO', b'SROCDOT_BHINM', b'RJ-SIR-BML-CES', b'10.84.6.206', b'NA', b'NA', b'NA', b'Network Down', b'02/Jan/2018 11:01:33']
[b'78', b'RJC', b'BAM', b'BAMCDOT_BARME', b'RJ-BMR-MAIN-CES', b'10.84.4.166', b'INS_ACT', b'INS_SBY', b'2/Jan/2018 10:12:02', b'Enabled', b'02/Jan/2018 10:47:37']
```